# Basic functional test in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do should I do a very basic functional test in node.js? here is the logic:

```
try {
    function a()...
    console.log("i am using function a");
} catch(err){
    console.log(err)
} or {
    function b()...
    console.log("i am using function b");
}
```

If the first function failed, print out the err log, and go on using second function, if not use the first function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only hit the `catch` block if your try block throws an exception. Effectively, the `catch` block is an `or`.

```
try {
  a();
  console.log("i am using function a");
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  b();
  console.log("i am using function b");
}
```